# I want to set a desired Location in Google map using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I added a Google map in ionic framework and it can access my location.
I want to add another location from Google map please give some instructions.

This is my controller

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $compile) {

```
$scope.init = function() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.07493,-89.381388);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);


    var contentString = "<div><a ng-click='clickTest()'>Click me!</a></div>";
    var compiled = $compile(contentString)($scope);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: compiled[0]
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    $scope.map = map;





};

// google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$scope.centerOnMe = function() {
    if(!$scope.map) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      var p1 =new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
      console.log(p1);
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
};





$scope.clickTest = function() {
    alert('Example of infowindow with ng-click')
};
```

})

;

Comment: Anybody Please help me

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i will get the center of the map but i want to get the latitude and longtitude in that position@shammon

Comment: So you want to set a marker with these locations?

Comment: yeah i want to mark this location @shammon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      var p1 =new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
      console.log(p1);
      //set up the marker for my location
      var mylocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:p1,
      map: map,
      title: 'My location'
    });
    }, function(error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
```

Comment: Please make my answer is correct so that other can refer it

Comment: Yeah i did it  @shammon